# Django Ceilometer get resource list and resource type

Tags: python, django, openstack, ceilometer

I am using Openstack Mitaka. 
In Django I am trying to get all the resources for tenants. (This is ok)
After that I need to understand the resource type. For example if it is an instance or floating ip, etc.

```
def sync_resources():
    logger.info("Executing sync_resources")
    sync_tenants()
    tenants = Tenant.objects.all()
    managers = Manager.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    for manager in managers:
        services = manager.services.all()
        regions = manager.region_set.all()
        for region in regions:
            ceilometer_driver = CeilometerDriver(region_name=region.name, **manager.ceilometer_params)
            if ceilometer_driver.is_authenticated:
                for tenant in tenants:
                    queries = [ceilometer_driver.make_query("project_id", ceilometer_driver.EQUAL, tenant.tenant_id)]
                    resource_list = ceilometer_driver.get_resource_list(query=queries)
```

In this code I get all the resources for a tenant. However I do not need all of them. And I will filter them based on list of types. Such as "Instance, floating_ip, volume, snapshot, etc"

Here is a sample resource detail:
[sample resource floating_ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruWrW.png)

from the metadata I can see that it is a floating_ip. However I cannot see somewhere in the details that its type floating ip. The metadata changes for different type of resources.

I alsoe checked from terminal with

```
$ ceilometer resource-list
$ ceilometer resource-show id-of-resource
```

Again the details are not helpful.

So I need a way to easily understand the resource type and match them with "Instance, floating ip, volume, snapshot, etc."

**Additional info:**

After some research I realized that I can get the type from link info. This doesn't work with "ceilometerclient" that I am using in the ceilometer_driver. 
I can get the additional link info when I call directly from REST API.

Here is a URL to call single project resource:

```
http://192.168.101.11:8777/v2/resources?q.field=project_id&q.value=63c40f56e11a4d24981710fd46285233
```

In results below is a sample for instance. I removed most of the links. But one link shows that it is an instance.

```
{
"user_id": "ec0d0110f44f42608814106a1f921a16",
"links": [
    {
        "href": "http://192.168.101.11:8777/v2/resources/e4d30a8e-e339-4c47-b71f-ec7061aaf113",
        "rel": "self"
    },
    {
        "href": "http://192.168.101.11:8777/v2/meters/instance?q.field=resource_id&q.value=e4d30a8e-e339-4c47-b71f-ec7061aaf113",
        "rel": "instance"
    },
    ...
],
"resource_id": "e4d30a8e-e339-4c47-b71f-ec7061aaf113",
"source": "openstack",
"last_sample_timestamp": "2018-03-15T14:18:15.368000",
"first_sample_timestamp": "2017-09-20T11:58:06.704000",
"project_id": "63c40f56e11a4d24981710fd46285233",
"metadata": {
    "instance_host": "node-6.reg1.test.skyatlas.com",
    "ephemeral_gb": "0",
    "flavor.vcpus": "1",
    "flavor.ephemeral": "0",
    "instance_id": "e4d30a8e-e339-4c47-b71f-ec7061aaf113",
    "display_name": "fuel service plugin",
    "state": "active",
    "flavor.ram": "2048",
    "status": "active",
    "ramdisk_id": "None",
    "flavor.name": "m1.small",
    "disk_gb": "20",
    "kernel_id": "None",
    "image.id": "4905099d-7912-4b00-b5bd-d8e1698dee92",
    "flavor.id": "2",
    "host": "b26c476c766c058541258e0c9275a738b889e0242be2af62fb331422",
    "OS-EXT-AZ.availability_zone": "test-1",
    "image.name": "Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)",
    "image_ref_url": "http://192.168.101.11:8774/images/4905099d-7912-4b00-b5bd-d8e1698dee92",
    "name": "instance-00000037",
    "flavor.disk": "20",
    "root_gb": "20",
    "image.links": "[{'href': 'http://192.168.101.11:8774/images/4905099d-7912-4b00-b5bd-d8e1698dee92', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]",
    "memory_mb": "2048",
    "instance_type": "m1.small",
    "vcpus": "1",
    "image_ref": "4905099d-7912-4b00-b5bd-d8e1698dee92",
    "flavor.links": "[{'href': 'http://192.168.101.11:8774/flavors/2', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]"
    }
}
```

Here is another one for floating ip:

```
{
"user_id": null,
"links": [
    {
        "href": "http://192.168.101.11:8777/v2/resources/f61e437d-dce3-4562-bd48-e14a6f0604f3",
        "rel": "self"
    },
    {
        "href": "http://192.168.101.11:8777/v2/meters/ip.floating?q.field=resource_id&q.value=f61e437d-dce3-4562-bd48-e14a6f0604f3",
        "rel": "ip.floating"
    },
    {
        "href": "http://192.168.101.11:8777/v2/meters/ip.floating.create?q.field=resource_id&q.value=f61e437d-dce3-4562-bd48-e14a6f0604f3",
        "rel": "ip.floating.create"
    }
],
"resource_id": "f61e437d-dce3-4562-bd48-e14a6f0604f3",
"source": "openstack",
"last_sample_timestamp": "2018-03-15T14:13:01.808000",
"first_sample_timestamp": "2018-02-14T06:33:51.663000",
"project_id": "63c40f56e11a4d24981710fd46285233",
"metadata": {
    "status": "DOWN",
    "router_id": "None",
    "floating_network_id": "3a15b9a4-8f93-4622-80e6-d57cfee53b43",
    "fixed_ip_address": "None",
    "floating_ip_address": "192.168.103.132",
    "port_id": "None"
    }
}
```

so an instance has a link with 
"rel": "instance"
and a floating ip has a link with
"rel": "ip.floating"

I think I can sort them out by REST API call instead of using the driver. 
However this so called solution does not seem to me the right way to go. 
So I still look for a better way of doing it. All the answers and inputs are welcome.